# Difference of sum of consecutive years pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this pandas DataFrame df

```
Date       | Year | Value
2017-01-01 | 2017 |   20
2017-01-12 | 2017 |   40
2018-01-12 | 2018 |  150
2019-10-10 | 2019 |  300
```

I want to calculate the difference between the total sum of Value per year between consecutive years. To get the total sum of Value per year I can do

```
df['YearlyValue'] = df.groupy('Year')['Value'].transform('sum')
```

which gives me

```
Date       | Year | Value | YearlyValue
2017-01-01 | 2017 |   20  |          60
2017-01-12 | 2017 |   40  |          60
2018-01-12 | 2018 |  150  |         150
2019-10-10 | 2019 |  300  |         300
```

but how can I get a new column 'Increment' has difference between YearlyValue of consecutive years?

Comment: Does this do what you want?: `df.groupby('Year')['Value'].transform('sum').diff()`

Comment: maybe not `transform('sum')`. Just `df.groupby('Year')['Value'].sum().diff()`.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik Your solution would return the difference only for the first Date of a different year and set 0 everywhere else (except in the first row which would result in nan). I would like each row to have the difference value as new column

Comment: @Quang Hoang your solution is closer to what I wanted. It does not create a new column but I can iterate over the returned Series and set the value myself.